# Any PHP plugin or library to generate .ase file using Pantone/NCS color types?

Tags: library, images, php

I need to generate an .ase color palette including hex, rgb, cmyk, cmyk c & u, Pantone C & U & NCS color types. I tried https://github.com/PureForm/ASE-Export but it doesn't support Pantone & NCS. Is there any other tool which supports especially Pantone C & U and NCS??